# Pokemon GO - can't detect my phone orientation

Tags: pokemon-go

has anyone found a solution to this? please let me know thank you!
i have tried everything as far as switching on and off the AR in a pokemon fight and moving my camera around or up and down. let me know if its just my phone or something in the settings that i dont know how to change..? TY

Answer (score -2):

It may be worth looking up your phones make and model to see if it has an internal gyroscope. Does it work for other apps? If it does have a gyroscope and doesnt work for other apps, it could be damaged.